# Garden hose washer installation - which way?

Tags: plumbing

If a garden hose washer has little 'ears' or 'tabs', is the washer inserted with them on the bottom or top?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A picture of what you mean would be really helpful here; please edit it into your question.

Comment: Washers with those ears are a cheap alternative to a full-width hose washer, which eliminates the problem and results in a more reliable seal. If I was faced with this question I'd throw the washer in the trash, where orientation isn't important, and install higher-quality washers.

Comment: I have had a lot of trouble squeezing in those "full-width hose washers". Maybe I was getting the wrong type or size. I like the ones with the ears.

Answer (score 1):

"Bottom" i.e. closer to the item the female hose thread fitting is on, not the side that the male hose thread item will contact. Those are intended to drop behind the hose threads (there is usually a gap) to help retain the washer in the hose fitting.

Comment: I would agree except that in some cases the void behind the threads is deeper, making the reverse more secure.

Comment: I don't think this is right...  If you push these items tab down into the female side away from the male, the tabs have nowhere to go.  The tabs should go towards the male connector, so that when you push them down into the female connector, the tabs use the higher threads to "lock" the gasket in place.